# `cv2.waitKey` raises "cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code"

Tags: python, opencv, mouseevent, keyboard-events, imshow

Let's say I have this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.zeros((1080, 1920, 3), np.uint8)

def click_event(event, x, y, flags, params):
    global myx, myy
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        myx = x
        myy = y
        print(myx, myy)
        key = cv2.waitKey(0)
        if key == 13:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            cv2.imshow('abc', img)
            print(myx * myy)
        if key == 97:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            return

cv2.imshow('freeze frame', img)
cv2.setMouseCallback('freeze frame', click_event)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print(myx + myy)
```

This code displays a black image, and prints out the x and y values of where you click on the image. And, if you press enter on your keyboard, it suppose to close the window and display the image again, and print the result of x multiplied by y. And, if you press on your keyboard `a`, the code stops and the window is closed.

But there is a problem, after I click the screen with my mouse, and click enter, it gives an error:

```
cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code
```

And the traceback refers to line 23, which is:

```
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

It seems like `waitKey` doesn't work with `destroyAllWindows`... But is there a workaround for this?

Comment: do not destroy the window, while you're in that loop. and rather re-use your 'freeze frame' window

Comment: @berak Thanks for the comment, how would I do that

Comment: you do that by using the same window name. why do you want to close one window and open a new one?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz An answer would help :)

Comment: literally use `cv2.imshow('freeze frame', img)` inside of the mouse event handler, and no need to destroy anything in there